# Safari address bar complete URL with keyboard shortcut

Tags: macos, keyboard, safari

Does Safari in OS X have a keyboard shortcut to complete a URL in the same fashion that Chrome does?

I'd like to be able to type in an incomplete address like `askdifferent`, press a key combo, and have Safari prefix it with `www.` and suffix with `.com`, and automatically navigate to that URL.

I've tried all various combination of <kbd>fn</kbd>, <kbd>control</kbd>, <kbd>option</kbd>,<kbd>command</kbd>, and <kbd>return</kbd>. Most of them will open your search in a new tab.

Does Safari support this, and what's the key combo?

Answer (score 3):

There IS a way - in Safari Version 10.0.3 at least.

Type a slash ("/") after the domain name. As in,

```
semiconducted/<enter>
```

will resolve to www.semiconducted.com

Voila!

Found at:
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4032903

Comment: Works with Safari 6.2.8 on OS X 10.8.5 too. Nice tip! +1

Comment: This isn't working on Safari 12.0.2 :(

Comment: Works in Safari 15.6.

Answer (score 2):

Safari 8.0 does: Press and hold the <kbd>Control</kbd> key for a moment while you’re editing the location and you’ll see the search icon turn into an icon indicating that it’s interpreting the input as (part of) a URL instead of performing a search. The label “Search *selected search engine*” next to your text will change to “Go to Site” and the ‘Go to Site “*your text*”’ menu item in the completions list will be selected. Typing <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd> will navigate there.

By the way, you can use <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> (next) and <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> (previous) to navigate through the completions list using the keyboard. (These are emacs-style navigation key bindings.)

Answer (score 1):

Safari doesn't support this out of the box.
You can do this with [**Keyboard Maestro**](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/) using a macro such as this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this.

1. You can of course use AutoHotKey(ahk) to define any key combo and mapping you want, which can be used in any text-editing environment, not necessarily in a url bar. So this is an overkill. (Other hotkey apps also work.)
2. Similar to Internet Explorer(or maybe Chrome, Firefox?), Safari also uses ctrl+enter(or return) as a shortcut to navigate to a website, which is illustrated in Chris Page's answer. However, a slight difference is that, in Safari, you have to hold the ctrl key for a moment(as mentioned in Chris Page's answer), while in Internet Explorer, you can simply hit ctrl+enter immediately after you type the address name, say, you type 'nba' in url bar, then hit ctrl+enter(no pause is needed), it will automatically navigate to www.nba.com . In fact, this shortcut can be found in Internet Explorer's help document.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using macOS Monterey ver. 12.5

Using the forward slash <kbd>\</kbd> after the name of the site seems to work:
<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> will result in `https://www.apple.com/`

If you press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, it will open a new window and go to the site.

Comment: `\ ` is called the backslash, not the (forward) slash. See [Punctuation: Slash](https://wmich.edu/writing/punctuation/slash)